# " ' " being converted into " &#8216; "

Tags: php, wordpress

```
    add_filter( 'comment_text', 'mh_commenttaglink' , 50 );

    function mh_commenttaglink( $text ) {

    // RegEx to find #tag, #hyphen-tag with letters and numbers
    $mh_regex = "/\#[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/";

    // Use that RegEx and populate the hits into an array
    preg_match_all( $mh_regex , $text , $mh_matches );

    // If there's any hits then loop though those and replace those hits with a link
    for ( $mh_count = 0; $mh_count < count( $mh_matches[0] ); $mh_count++ )
            {
                    $mh_old = $mh_matches[0][$mh_count];
                    $mh_old_lesshash = str_replace( '#' , ' ' , $mh_old );
                    $mh_new = str_replace( $mh_old , '<a href="' . get_bloginfo( url ) . '/?s=%23' . $mh_old_lesshash . '"/ rel="tag">' . $mh_old . '</a>' , $mh_matches[0][$mh_count] );
                    $text = str_replace( $mh_old  , $mh_new , $text );
            }
    // Return any substitutions
    return $text;
    }
```

I have a small custom plugin for wordpress here that converts all hashtagged terms in post comments into searchable links.

I know this plugin is causing the issue as it only buggers off after deactivation, I just cant see where in this code I need to edit something out or add somethign in to prevent it.

More experienced eyes would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the  get_bloginfo function?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo 'url' - Returns the "Site address (URL)" set in Settings > General. This data is retrieved from the "home" record in the wp_options table. Equivalent to home_url().